# Was Steve Jobs a Buddhist?

Tags: modern-world, lay-buddhism

I've heard Steve Jobs described as a Buddhist but is that actually true? I know that he was married by Zen monks but did he actually have a Buddhist practice, meditate or was associated with a particular sangha. Or was it just more of an interest with him rather than him actually identifying as a Buddhist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just google him? I see dozens of articles. Including:

- [What Kind of Buddhist was Steve Jobs, Really?](http://blogs.plos.org/neurotribes/2011/10/28/what-kind-of-buddhist-was-steve-jobs-really/) PLosOneBlog
- [Here's How Zen Meditation Changed Steve Jobs' Life And Sparked A Design Revolution](http://uk.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-zen-meditation-buddhism-2015-1?r=US&IR=T). Business Insider
- [Steve Jobs' private spirituality now an open book](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/religion/story/2011-11-02/steve-jobs-faith-buddhism/51049772/1). USAToday.

Take your pick. I don't see how StackExchange/Buddhism is going to help you here. Unless of course there is someone who writes answers that knew him personally, we're all reliant on what is in the media.

Comment: Fair point. I'm going to delete this question

Comment: Actually I've changed my mind. I don't think it's so bad thing that these links are on the site so I'm going to undelete. I take your point about the question being poor.